# Question about delegate and protocol in swift (with example)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to work with delegate and protocol but met a problem.

I created 2 buttons on one ViewController and created 1 imageView in another ShowViewController. The color of the imageView will change according to which button is pressed.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol getColorProtocol {
    func getColor(color:String?)
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var color: String?

    var delegate:getColorProtocol?

    @IBAction func blueButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        color = "blue"
        delegate?.getColor(color: color)
    }

    @IBAction func redButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        color = "red"
        delegate?.getColor(color: color)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }



}
```

ShowViewController.swift

```
import UIKit


class ShowViewController: UIViewController, getColorProtocol {

    var viewOne = ViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIImageView!

    func getColor(color: String?) {
        print("color is \(color!)")

        if color == "red"{
            colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        }
        else if color == "blue" {
            colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

        }


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewOne.delegate = self

    }

}
```

[press here to view the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOGaR.jpg)!

You may check my storyboard above.

Currently, it has no error but it cannot call the getColor function. I am wondering if the problem is coming from the `delegate?.getColor(color: color)` statement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your case, you don't need to use delegate pattern

Your `ViewController` connect directly to `ShowViewController` through `segue`
You can use `prepareForSegue` instead

Secondly, I don't think you understand how `delegate pattern` works,
Inside ShowViewController, you're create a new `ViewController` called `viewOne`, it isn't the original `ViewController` so that's why your code doesn't work as expected

As I mentioned above, you should use `segue`

first, go to the `storyboard` setup your segue identifier. Then, inside your `ViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "goToShowVC") {
    //your code here
}
}
```

Comment: yes you are right. I still feel confused when using delegate so that I create this to clarify my concept. Thanks a lot.
But I still can't get it why the delegate pattern is not working here. Delegate and protocol is used to pass object between classes, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a delegate for this, but just prepare for segue. I see that you have two segues set up already, so in your viewcontroller, assuming your segues are called "blue" and "red" in your storyboard, you could add:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ShowViewController {
        if segue.identifier == "blue" {
            destinationVC.color = UIColor.blue
        } else if segue.identifier == “red” {
            destinationVC.color = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

then you would want to add a color variable to manipulate in your showviewcontroller. For example:

```
var color = UIColor.white
colorview.backgroundcolor = color
```